# parseInt() method. Keep getting Null Pointer Exception on highlighted line

Tags: parseint

just been trying to convert a string into an Integer so that I can use it for something else but I keep falling into the null pointer exception trap.

```
public class ConvertToInt {
private InputReader reader;

public int changeToInteger(String word){

// Problem i've got is just below, I keep getting a null point exception on this line each time     
// I want to return the result.

       return reader.convertToInt(word); // null ponter exception on this line
    }
}
```

parseInt method from InputReader class:

```
/**
 * Convert the given word to an integer.
 * @param word The word to be converted.
 * @return The integer represented by word.
 * @throws NumberFormatException if word is not an integer.
 */
public int convertToInt(String word)
{
    return Integer.parseInt(word);
}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `reader`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Many thanks. I couldn't believe I didn't spot this a while ago.